# Where does the Style Manager store the files in and Why does the Style Manager does not show some edit color ramps?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, symbology, color

[image]

Where are Color Ramp files saved? Every time I make edits, it does not show up on the Style Manager. Does it save it to the hard drive or in the Style Manager?
I need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will help much (as I think stretched and discrete ramps cannot be applied to other datasets.  I am not very versed in the raster side of this.)
Here is what I know about the vector side of style manager.

if you go to the customize pulldown and select the style manager.

[image: pulldown]

It will show you the styles you have active.

[image: manager]

The default location (win7) is c:\users\myloginname\appdata\roaming\esri\desktop 10.x\arcmap
However you can put a file anywhere you like and load it. (perhaps to share with someone else on the network)

[image: load a style]

Now let's get back to what you need.
IF you are wanting to use the same raster in multiple documents with the same layer settings.  Then follow steps 1 and 2.
Then just drag in that lyr file any time you want to use that raster with those settings. (hint: you can have more than one lyr with different settings and all using the same raster).
If you want to apply to another raster follow steps 3 and 4.

What you want to do is to

1. go to the raster layer (in table of contents).
2. save as a layer file

   [image: export]
3. then in other raster layers go to the layer properties > symbology
   tab.

   [image: import]
4. select the import button and import the lyr file.
   BTW the save button next to the import (lyr) btton doesn't save an lyr. It saves an xml.
   I haven't ever used it.